# Numerical integration of highly oscillating function

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to Numerically integrate the following function

```
int[t_] := NIntegrate[A1[t - t3 - t2 - t1]*A2[t - t3 -t2]*A3[t - t3]*Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + 
   t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2))], {t1, 0, 500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

Take h=5 (it doesn't matter in this case). A1, A2 and A3 are some interpolating function. So I want to use MonteCarlo method because A1, A2 and A3 are not converging properly in "Global Adaptive" method (or takes very long time to converge), but coverging quickly in MonteCarlo.

```
int[t_] := NIntegrate[A1[t - t3 - t2 - t1]*A2[t - t3 - t2]*A3[t - t3]
, {t1, 0, 500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

This  converges perfectly fine.
However,

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + 
    t3) +h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2))], {t1, 0, 500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500},Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

this is not coverging at all (My deduction is that the exponential function is highly oscillating). Is it possible to somehow converge this function using some precursors?

Comment: `h = 5;  Integrate[
 Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2))], {t1, 0, 500}, {t2, 
  0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}]` results in `1/750 I (-1 + E^(2500 I))^2 (1 + E^(2500 I)) (-1 + E^(7500 I)`. Its numerical value equals `0.00110115 + 0.00178614 I`. The one is close to zero and this explains the problems with the numerical integration since the modulus of the integrand equals `1`.

Comment: Let NIntegrate choose method automaticaly, is very exact and causes no problems  `NIntegrate[
 Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2)) /. h -> 5], {t1, 0, 
  500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}] `   `(*   0.00110115 + 0.00178614 I   *)`

Comment: @Akku14 I know that, but the problem is I cannot choose Global Adaptive method for A1, A2 and A3. That's the problem. So, when you combine the two integrands, it won't converge.

Comment: BTW, the integral `Integrate[
 Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2))], {t1, 0, 
  Infinity}, {t2, 0, Infinity}, {t3, 0, Infinity}]` diverges for `h>=0`.

Comment: Show us the A1 ,A2 ,A3

Comment: You show A1,A2,A3 ranging from -300 to 300. But you integrate `A1[t - t3 - t2 - t1] ` with t1, t2, t3 from 0 to 500. Therefore you get wide outside the range and then  extrapolation is done. May be that is the problem.

Comment: @Akku14 I already addressed that problem, by extending the domain from -inf to inf using a piecewise function.

Comment: @Akku14: Your claim "Let NIntegrate choose method automaticaly, is very exact and causes no problems "  does not correspond to reality in view of `NIntegrate[  Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2)) /. h -> 5], {t1, 0,    500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500},Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] ` which results in `-151812. - 60762.9 I` and an error communication.

Comment: @user64494,    `"SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 ` is not automatic. Is a manual intervention. Automatic means, that you let NIntegrate automatically recognize, that part of integration can be done analytically.

Comment: @Akku14: In any case, `NIntegrate[  Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2)) /. h -> 5], {t1, 0,    500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}]`  uses symbolic processing, not numeric methods for that integration.

Comment: @sslucifer: [Method of stationary phase](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stationary_phase,_method_of_the) is used to this end. Unfortunately, MSP is not implemented in Mathematica as yet.

Comment: one more word @user64494 . what kind of person are you? It seems that you can not live without criticizing others,  against the facts. Automatically means without options, like my example. Your example is not automatic! By the way, the comment was addressed to the owner of the post, not to you. What are you interfering. Mind your own business.  You are repeatedly negative. On notorious troublemakers we can do without.

Comment: @Akku14 and user64494, your comments helped me a lot to find this answer.

Comment: @user64494 Method of stationary phase is actually a good reference and that's how I found Levin rule method. Unfortunately, MSP doesn't work in my case, as its condition is not being satisfied my integrand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get any answer, I did some digging in the docs of [NIntegrate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337) and I found a reasonable method,

```
int[t_] := NIntegrate[A1[t - t3 - t2 - t1]*A2[t - t3 -t2]*A3[t - t3]*Exp[I*(h*(t1 + t2 + t3) + h*(t1) + h*(t1 + t2))]
, {t1, 0, 500}, {t2, 0, 500}, {t3, 0, 500}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {"ExpRelated"}, "Points" -> 2}"]
```

So if you have an integrand of the form $f(x)*g(x)$, where $f(x)$ is non-oscillating and $g(x)$ is highly oscillating, one can use the Levin rule. In my case, the integrand is exactly of the form. The efficiency is not as good as I would like, but this is the best I came up with.

Comment: All that is not so simple. Up to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html), the Levin rule is applicable to one-dimensional integrals only. Amn't I right?

Comment: @user64494 Most of the example in the doc is for one dimensional integral, but it is nowhere written as it is only applicable for one dimensional. In my case, the 3-dimensional integral works well for Levin rule.

Comment: Your claim "Most of the example in the doc is for one dimensional integral" does not correspond to reality: only the one-dimensional case is considered in the documentation. I'd like to quote e.g. "A Levin-type rule estimates the integral of an oscillatory function by approximating the antiderivative as a product of a polynomial and the oscillatory part of the integrand". I don't know any antiderivatives for multiple integrals. 
  Sorry, "In my case, the 3-dimens[c]ional integral works well for Levin rule" are empty words. Deep regard.